# I want ignore the failure of keyword based on condition and continue to next keyword to already existing huge set of test cases and suits

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

I know we can write a listener to run the keyword when there is a failure in the keyword by checking the status of the keyword in the listener. But one of my requirements apart from looking at the Status, I want to look at the error message also before I run the keyword.

RunListner.py

```
def _end_keyword(self, name, attributes):
    if attributes['status'] == 'FAIL':
```

The above portion of code in the listeners will help me to check the status of Keyword, but no way I can check the reason for the failure of the keyword.
Is there something like this possible?

```
def _end_keyword(self, name, attributes):
        if attributes['status'] == 'FAIL' and ErrorMessage==""something went wrong"" :
```

At present I don't have idea how to pass on the error information to listner .

RobotCode

```
*** Settings ***
    Documentation    Suite description
    Library          RunListner
    Test Template   Run Keyword And Ignore Error
    Suite Setup    Set Keyword To Run On Failure    Log Many    1    2   3
    
*** Test Cases ***
Test title
    log   step one
    log   step two
    fail  something went wrong
    fail  something else went wrong
    log   last step
```

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot the failure reason is "something went wrong" is one of failure and the other is "Something else went wrong". I want to call listener only when "something went wrong"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *exactly* the case of the `Fail` keyword, you can get that from its `'args'` key - this keyword does one thing, and that is to fail with a message - so it's argument will be what you can compare with.

But that (logic) will be applicable only for the `Fail` keyword; for example, in this:

```
Should Be True      1 == 2
```

, the value of the `'args'` is `['1 == 2']` - not very usable.

There's an alternative, though - you may go after the `log_message` listener, and intercept the "FAIL" level:

```
    def _log_message(self, message):
        if message['level'] == 'FAIL':
            print(f'inside listener: {message}')
```

These are logged on failures (duh :), and there's a key holding the message itself; in the case of the "should be true" example below, it looks like this:
`'message': "'1 == 2' should be true."`

E.g. the final message one would see in the log - and more or less, what you are after in your approach.

Comment: Thanks for your response, It looks amazing :-). I think I can replace the `_end_keyword` function with the `_log_message` which you have mentioned above as I can verify both the test case status and the failure cause(by use of `level` and `message` key) . I hope am correct with this. Any other thoughts?

Comment: "Any other thoughts?" - a lot, but on the topic - not that much :D Use the `_log_message` with a bit of caution - in some cases you may want to catch a failure (`Run Keyword And Return Status`, or `Ignore Exception`), but it will still fire off; so make sure the conditions you put in it are tight, up to your expectations.

Comment: Yup ! I ll be using with `Run keyword And Ignore error ` where I ll make sure it up to the perfect check !